# JQuery - filter table by class of children's buttons or id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, html-table

it's the first question I ask here, so just delete it, if its too specific,  and I'm sorry for your time. I'll try to do it better the next time :) But everything I found here and at Google is not helpful for me and I cannot figure out, how to do it right. And just because I couldn't find something similar, I think, this question could help more people than just me:

Following situation:

[Example of the given table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofl2k.png)

This is a normal HTML-Table built up by PHP.

```
<tr class="tablerow" data-id='{id}'>
<td class='spalte1' id=del{id}>
    <input class='delbutton imagebutton'
           type='image' src='src/mülleimer.png' title='ID {id} löschen' data-id={id}
           />
</td>
<td class='interpret' id='interpret{id}' title='Interpret'>{Interpret}</td>
<td class='songtitel' id='songtitel{id}' title='Songtitel'>{Songtitel}</td>
<td class='status' id='status{id}' title='Flags'>{Statusbar}</td>
<td class='utilbar' id='utilbar_header{id}'>{Utilbar}{audioplayer}
    <div class='eingabe_linkDiv' id='eingabe_linkDiv{id}' style='display:none'>
        <input type='text' class='eingabe_link' data-id='{id}'/>

    </div>
</td>
```

Everything surrounded by curly braces will be replaced row by row with it's equivalent for the given id.

```
static function getStatusbar($id) {
    $outputFrame = '<div id = "addedFlags">{added}</div><div id = "allFlags">{all}</div>';
    $outputAdded = "";
    $outputAll = "";
    $output = "";
    $active = Main::getDatenbank()->getFlags($id);
    $all = php\Flag::getAll();
    foreach ($all as $i => $flag) {
        if (in_array($flag, $active)) {
            $outputAdded .= $flag->getButtonString($id, "added");
            $outputAll .= $flag->getButtonString($id, "all", true);
        } else {
            $outputAll .= $flag->getButtonString($id, "all", true);
            $outputAdded .= $flag->getButtonString($id, "added", true);
        }
    }
    $output = str_replace("{added}", $outputAdded, $outputFrame);
    $output = str_replace("{all}", $outputAll, $output);

    return $output;
}
```

//in Flag-class: $addedall is a string 'added' (to the filter) or 'all'

```
function getButtonString($id, $addedall, $hidden = false) {
    $output = "<input "
            . "class='imagebutton statusbutton ".$this->type." ".$this->type."button$id' "
            . $hidden ? "style='display:none' ":""
            . "type='image' src='src/$this->filename.png' "
            . "title='$this->title' "
            . "data-id=$id data-type='$this->type' data-a='$addedall'/>";
    return $output;
}
```

Now I want to filter the rows of the table by the flags added to the Table-Header. The Header has a statusbar-section with the imagebuttons, like every row. So if a button is selected in the filter, i only want to show the rows, which have the same buttons added (="made show", not added. every row has every button, but the most are hidden). In this example all "german" songs, sang by "men", played on a "guitar" and about "love".

What's the best way to do it? The flags, that were added to the filter, are stored at the db and I can grab them easily, but looping through the bidimensional array does not want to work.

```
function filter() {
$("#Table_Songlist tr").show();
$.get('db/getAllFlags.php', function (output) {
    var allflags = JSON.parse(output);
    var filter = JSON.parse(allflags[0]);//filtersettings are stored in db with id 0
    for (var id in allflags) {
        var flagarray = JSON.parse(allflags[id]);
        for (var index in flagarray) {
            if (!$.inArray(flagarray[index], filter)) {
                $("tr").filter(function () {
                    return $(this).attr('data-id') == id;
                }).hide();
            }
        }
    }
});

public function getAllFlags() {
    try {
        $a = array();
        $rs = $this->pdo->query("SELECT * FROM songhasflag ORDER BY id");
        foreach ($rs as $row) {
            $a[$row['id']][] = $row['flag'];
        }
        return $a;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        die($ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

and the .php

```
$a = \repertoire\Main::getDatenbank()->getAllFlags();
$b = array();
foreach($a as $id => $flagarray) {
    $b[$id] = json_encode($flagarray);
}
echo json_encode($b);
```

Or is it even better to try it with Dom-Traversal, so that I get all tr-children, which contain the shown buttons of the header? I couldn't even imagine, how this code should look like.. 
Has anyone got an idea, how I can make the rows disappear, that do not match the filter in the header?

Comment: In the `filter()` JS function, instead of doing `$.get()`, perhaps you can try with `$( 'tr:has(input[data-a="added"])' ).hide();`? But I'm not sure though, if I understand the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to make it clearer in the edit. In your answer is no connection to the selected filters.

Comment: btw, according to your snippet every row of your table will have the same IDs. this is not allowed in HTML. If you don't need the IDs then remove them or just use the {id} variable to make it really unique.

Comment: Ahh, ok, thanks for the hint, i will change it :)

Comment: How about changing `!$.inArray(flagarray[index], filter)` to `$.inArray(flagarray[index], filter) <= -1`

Comment: Ahhh.. that will be my problem. It returns an index, not the boolean. Thank you!

Comment: So would you upvote my comment? xD Well I mean, I'm glad you got it working. =)

Comment: I would, but where? I cannot find the button for that.. -.- Do I need any reputation to do that?

Comment: Actually yes, you do need at least 15 rep to upvote comments. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365 So never mind about upvoting my comment, and all the best in your projects!

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I will come back, when I have collected enough reputation ;)